# error while reading data from mysql database using ASP.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I trying to read data from mysql database using ASP.net as shown below 
but I get message error that says

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Configuration;

namespace BankingDemo
{
    public partial class AccountInquiry : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstr = @"Server=127.0.0.1;Database=Mysql;Uid=root;Pwd=system;";
            /*string ConnStr;
            ConnectionStringSettings ConnSet = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnConfig"];

            if (ConnSet == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnSet.ConnectionString))
            {
                throw new Exception("Fatal error: missing connecting string in web.config file");
                ConnStr = ConnSet.ConnectionString;
            }*/

            string cmdtxt = @"select Name,CountryCode,District,Population from world.city";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtxt);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            string temp="";

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                temp += reader["Name"].ToString();
                temp += reader["CountryCode"].ToString();
                temp += reader["District"].ToString();
                temp += reader["Population"].ToString();
                temp += "<br />";
            }

            conn.Close();

            lbl_CityName.Text = temp;

        }
    }
}
```

code markup below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AccountInquiry.aspx.cs" Inherits="BankingDemo.AccountInquiry" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Banking Site (Demo)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CityName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</body>
</html>
```

my MySQL connector for .Net  is installed as shown at image [image]

Comment: did you mean `127.0.0.1` instead of `127.0.0.10`?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes the localhost ip address

Comment: I think you are not getting the hint. You have a typo in your connection string. That error always means there is a connection problem and almost always means your connection string is wrong.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or are you using SQL Server?...

Comment: You need to use the MySQL connector for .Net

Comment: @Crowcoder I get your hint but that's wont solve the issue I had changed the `127.0.0.10` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @MarkC. I am using MySql

Comment: @ngeksyo I think it is insatlled with mysql installer

Comment: You need to use nuget and search MySQL.data.. sqlconnection is a sql server client and not MySQL..

Comment: That connection string does not look correct for MySQL.

Comment: @MarkC. I am not finding the error my friend 
i tried removing the`;` at the end of connection string 
or using  this `Server=127.0.0.1;Database=Mysql;Uid=root;Pwd=system;` 
or this `Server=127.0.0.1;Database=Mysql;User Id=root;Password=system;`

Comment: @ngeksyo please see  image attached the I think its installed I am I right ?

Comment: Please check you reference if you have MySQL.data if your ref asm. This is not automatic even though you have MySQL.data in gal..

Comment: You are using `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`. These are only for MS SQL Server. You need to use the `MySqlConnection`, etc., like ngeksyo says.

Comment: @ngeksyo Thank you my friend you were right problem solved please post your comment as answer so i'll marked an answer

Comment: @MarkC. thanks you too my friend for your appreciated help

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks you too my friend for your appreciated help please post your comment as answer